# Api command for tree structure of docker images

Tags: docker

Is there any docker api command available to get the tree structure in json format. In docker cli

```
docker images --tree
```

will gave tree structure of docker images.

Comment: I think that functionality has been removed from the CLI.

Comment: Nop.. I got the answer just now.

Comment: Remote API or Command, which do you want? The command option was deprecated by https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/5001.

Comment: `$ docker images --tree
flag provided but not defined: --tree
See 'docker images --help'.
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.7.0, build 0baf609`

Answer (score 0):

as @yanana mentioned, this command is deprecated from currently docker versions since docker develop team believe it is not a core function to docker and they don't want docker code to be large.

However, there is a third-party project that can be used to get the tree of the images.

https://github.com/justone/dockviz

you can use it like:

./dockviz_linux_amd64 images -d | dot -Tpng -o image.png

then, you can get a picture in image.png that describes the image tree.